# What is the explicit keyword for in c++?

Tags: c++, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the explicit keyword in C++ mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

```
explicit CImg(const char *const filename):_width(0),_height(0),_depth(0),_spectrum(0),_is_shared(false),_data(0) {
  assign(filename);
}
```

what's the difference with or without it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's use to decorate constructors; a constructor so decorated cannot be used by the compiler for implicit conversions.

C++ allows up to one user-provided conversion, where "user-provided" means, "by means of a class constructor", e.g., in :

```
 class circle {
   circle( const int r ) ;
 }

  circle c = 3 ; // implicit conversion using ctor
```

the compiler will call the circle ctor here, constructinmg circle `c` with a value of 3 for `r`.

`explicit` is used when you don't want this. Adding explicit means that you'd have to *explicitly* construct:

```
 class circle {
   explicit circle( const int r ) ;
 }

  // circle c = 3 ; implicit conversion not available now
  circle c(3); // explicit and allowed
```

Answer (score 5):

The `explicit` keyword prevents implicit conversions.

```
// Does not compile - an implicit conversion from const char* to CImg
CImg image = "C:/file.jpg"; // (1)
// Does compile
CImg image("C:/file.jpg"); // (2)

void PrintImage(const CImg& img) { };

PrintImage("C:/file.jpg"); // Does not compile (3)
PrintImage(CImg("C:/file.jpg")); // Does compile (4)
```

Without the `explicit` keyword, statements (1) and (3) would compile because the compiler can see that a `const char*` can be implicitly converted to a `CImg` (via the constructor accepting a `const char*`). Sometimes this implicit conversion is undesirable because it doesn't always make sense.